# What does $P(X;Y)$ mean in the David Williams book?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

From the David Williams book problem e10.5, for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and for every $n$, there is an equality:

$P(T>kN) = P(T>kN;T>(k-1)N)$

Is that supposed to mean:

$P(T>kN) = P(T>kN\textbf{1}_{T>(k-1)N})$

In the book, $E(X;Y) = E(X\textbf{1}_{Y} )$

Is it the same for probability?

Comment: You have that $\mathbb P(A) = \mathbb E(\textbf{1}_A)$, so usually conditional probability is defined as $\mathbb P(A;Y) = \mathbb E(\textbf{1}_A ;Y)$. Also I'm not sure if the line before the question is correct - for $Y$ an event of small probability $\varepsilon$ and $X = 1$ constant a.s., then $\mathbb E(X \textbf 1_Y) = \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

For two events $A$ and $B$, $P(A;B)$ denotes $P(A\cap B)$.

In the particular setting of the question, $A=\{T>kN\}$ and $B=\{T>(k-1)N\}$
hence $A\subset B$ and the equality is then clear.